# Where should I place hook_block_view_alter?

Tags: 8, blocks

this may be a trivial question, but I have no clue to how to get this working. I have this theme 'nexus'. When try the hook

```
function nexus_preprocess_block(&$variables)
```

in the file nexus.theme, it works,

but `function nexus_block_view_alter(&$data, $block)` 
doesn't.

Should I put it in a module? I tried creating a module using hello_world example, and put in the the module's controller but no avail.

Any hint would be much helpful.

Comment: Try with `function nexus_block_view_alter(array &$build, \Drupal\Core\Block\BlockPluginInterface $block) `

Comment: Yes that would need to go into a .module file. Did you enable your hello_world module and then flush all caches? and also change the function name to hello_world_block_view_alter if "hello_world" is your module name?

Comment: ah..this worked..somehow I ended up with a controller as given in the helloworld example and it didn't worked out...now I put it as .module file and prefixed the hook with module name, it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In drupal 8 the declaration of `hook_block_view_alter` changed from `hook_block_view_alter(&$data, $block)` (Drupal7) to  `hook_block_view_alter(array &$build, \Drupal\Core\Block\BlockPluginInterface $block)` (Drupal 8).
For more info check [hook_block_view_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21block%21block.api.php/function/hook_block_view_alter/8.2.x) Documentation page.

`hook_block_view_alter` be better in custom module not theme, see [guide to building basic Drupal 8 module](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/a-practical-guide-to-building-basic-drupal-8-modules), and flush all caches.

Answer (score 0):

While normally the alter hooks are invoked also when they are implemented from the theme used to render the page, there are cases where this doesn't happen. The method that invokes `hook_entity_view()`, `hook_entity_view_alter()`, `hook_ENTITY_TYPE_view()`, and `hook_ENTITY_TYPE_view_alter()`, [`EntityViewBuilder::buildMultiple()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21EntityViewBuilder.php/function/EntityViewBuilder%3A%3AbuildMultiple/8.6.x), invokes only module hooks.

```
  $this->moduleHandler()->invokeAll($view_hook, [
    &$build_list[$key],
    $entity,
    $display,
    $view_mode,
  ]);
  $this->moduleHandler()->invokeAll('entity_view', [
    &$build_list[$key],
    $entity,
    $display,
    $view_mode,
  ]);

  // ...

  // Allow modules to modify the render array.
  $this->moduleHandler()->alter([$view_hook, 'entity_view', ], $build_list[$key], $entity, $display);
```

In a theme, you can implement `hook_preprocess_block()`, but the other hooks require a module.